# Are Draco and Harry related?

Tags: harry-potter

They say that all pure-blood wizarding families are related. The Potters are pure-bloods and so are the Malfoys; so, **are Harry and Draco related?**

Comment: Welcome to the site =) Good question - although complete with answer I think! Canon does say that all the pure-blood families are distantly related so the answer is yes, distantly, it seems. But there again even in real societies without the elevated levels of inter-family marriage this will be true to some extent: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CNE_1XvJo6g

Comment: [Kinda?](https://hugelolcdn.com/i/38266.gif)

Comment: Didn't they kiss each other in the end of *The Cursed Child*? It implied that they were going to marry each other. Draco's wife was already dead and Harry is either gay or bisexual. Even if, let's say, Harry wouldn't divorce Ginny for the sake of his children, Draco and Harry could be secret couples or maybe Wizarding Laws allow multiple spouses.

Comment: @SachinStark When did that happen? Harry kissing Draco?? Euurgh!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Kinda?

In 2005, J.K. Rowling drew a copy of the Black Family Tree for producer David Heyman. **It shows us that Draco's first cousin, three times removed had married a "Charlus Potter".** Nothing more was ever said about this Charlus Potter, but unless this is [another one of Rowling's fiascos](https://web.archive.org/web/20110430144617/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=49), we can probably assume he's related to Harry.

> [image]

They are likely related in many other ways as well, seeing as both the Malfoy's and Potter's were pure-blood families.

> “The pure-blood families are all interrelated,” said Sirius. “If you’re only going to let your sons and daughters marry purebloods your choice is very limited, there are hardly any of us left.
>   <sub>*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* - Chapter Six</sub>

Also, as [Ailuropoda melanoleuca points out](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/157649/55866), "Harry's godfather Sirius is cousins with Draco's mother", though that's not a genetic relation.

Comment: Charlus's son would have to be James' dad (or, I suppose, James himself) for Harry and Draco to be this closely related by blood. In which case, Sirius would be  an even closer relative to Harry than Draco, which he might have mentioned.

Comment: @RDFozz - He isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in two ways:

1. Harry's father is a pure blood and all pure bloods are related
2. Harry's godfather Sirius is cousins with Draco's mother

Comment: Good answer, however it is worth noting that a godfather is not a blood relation, so sirius's relatives don't neccesarily share blood with harry (or james )

Comment: @Hesperus -- on the other hand, the OP only asked if Draco and Harry were "related." Didn't specify: "Is there evidence of a *genetic* relationship involving at least one common ancestor within the last 10 generations?" or anything along those lines.

Comment: @Lorendiac Yes, but in these kind of questions, 'related' usually means genetically, so it's probably safe to presume that's the intended meaning.

Comment: @Lorendiac - if the"godfather" relationship counted, then sure they're related - they were in the same class/grade at Hogwarts.